# Need an advice of framework for path on map validation

Tags: java, algorithm, perl, geolocation, geospatial

The problem I am facing is as follows:

Given two polygons defining the borders of a maze and a path in between (see picture below), I would like to know when I crossed the borders of the maze.

In respect to the inputs I have:

- One file defining edges of the two polygons (only the points that
  connect straight lines)
- One file with all waypoints I had visited, in the order of appearance

I need to calculate a score for that path based on the amount of time spent in the restricted zone.

**What is the best way to do it? (Algorithm/Technology/Library) I have no technology restrictions so the solution can be anything e.g Java, C, Perl (this is my favorite), etc**

I started working on a solution, but then I realized this issue must have been solved millions of times in the past and there's no reason for "reinventing the wheel" :)

I am new to Geographic/Geometric kind of problems, and I would greatly appreciate any advice of what approach should I take.

Cheers

[image: example map]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a  [Point in polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)

1. Build a list of polygons from "One file defining edges of the two
   polygons (only the points that connect straight lines)"
2. Apply point_in_polygon() ([perl implementation](http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-win32-users/394/), your favorite)
   for each "waypoints I had visited"

Comment: welcome to SO! thanks for the sharp answer - works like a charm!